# Authorization has been denied for this request while accessing WebAPI from MVC 5(Azure AD)

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-active-directory, authorization, webapi

So, I was trying to call a WebAPI ToDoList from MVC 5 while I am getting the access token from Azure AD and the token is sent being sent as here: request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", appToken). But no matter what the authorization resulted as:-
StatusCode : 401,
Rephrase: Authorization has been denied.
However I followed the microsoft azure articles, forums with no success although the same authorization is working in the NativeClientApp, .NET Core.

Please Note: WebAPI project and MVC project are in the same solution.

```
  public async Task<string> GetTokenForApplication()
    {
        string signedInUserID = 
    ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        string tenantID = 
    ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
        string userObjectID = 
    ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

// Get a token for the Graph without triggering any user interaction (from the cache, via multi-resource refresh token, etc)
        ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
        // Initialize AuthenticationContext with the token cache of the currently signed in user, as kept in the app's database
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceID, clientcred, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
        return appToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }




public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
        string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
      //  
        try
        {
            Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceID);
            Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantID);
            appToken = string.Empty;
            ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot,
                  async () => await GetTokenForApplication());

            // Use the token for querying the graph to get the user details

            var result = await activeDirectoryClient.Users
                .Where(u => u.ObjectId.Equals(userObjectID))
                .ExecuteAsync();
            IUser user = result.CurrentPage.ToList().First();

            List<TodoItem> itemList = new List<TodoItem>();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, todoListBaseAddress + "api/todolist");
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", appToken);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                List<Dictionary<String, String>> responseElements = new List<Dictionary<String, String>>();
                JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
                String responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                responseElements = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<String, String>>>(responseString, settings);
                foreach (Dictionary<String, String> responseElement in responseElements)
                {
                    TodoItem newItem = new TodoItem();
                    newItem.Title = responseElement["Title"];
                    newItem.Owner = responseElement["Owner"];
                    itemList.Add(newItem);
                }

                return View();
            }

            return View(user);
        }
        catch (AdalException ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
            // Return to error page.
            return View("Error");
        }
        // If the above failed, the user needs to explicitly re-authenticate for the app to obtain the required token
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
            return View("Relogin");
        }
    }
```

Comment: How did you get the token?

Comment: Hi, @JoyWang I got token from Azure AD. Check the code for that mentioned above in the question.

Comment: @JoyWang Let me know have any suggestions as I have tried all, even somewhere it was written this no longer supports in MVC.

Comment: @Rinkesh did you checked old MS examples for very similar use case: `Call a web API in an ASP.NET Core web app using Azure AD` ? Step by step guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/calling-a-web-api-in-an-aspnet-core-web-application-using-azure-ad/ 
Sample code: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/tree/master

Comment: Ya I have checked these, but these samples are for aspnet core and its assemblies like: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorize doesn't support my MVC project. Any suggestions on how to implement these?

Comment: {StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcU3d4TWFwUHJvRGV2MDNcc291cmNlXHJlcG9zXEF6dXJlV2ViQXBpXEF6dXJlV2ViQXBpXGFwaVx0b2RvbGlzdA==?=
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Thu, 30 Jul 2020 05:09:54 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 61
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}



**<<<this is the message I always get.**

Comment: @LukeDuda Let me know if there any help for me.

Comment: Here are some [asp.net samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/sample-v1-code#web-api-calling-microsoft-graph-or-another-web-api) that could help you.